# Congruence properties of $x_1^6+x_2^6+x_3^6+x_4^6+x_5^6 = z^6$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

It is known that given *primitive* (co-prime) integer solutions to,

$$x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4+x_4^4 = z^4$$

then there is one $x_i$ such that  $z^4-x_i^4$ is divisible by $d_4=5^4$. Additionally, Ward showed that *if one of the $x_i$ is zero*, then there is the further constraint that $z\pm x_j$ is divisible by $w_4=2^{10}$. For example, we have,

$$673865^4+ 1390400^4+ 2767624^4 = 2813001^4$$

and,

$$z+x_3 = 2813001 + 2767624 = 5^4\cdot 8929$$

$$z-x_1 = 2813001 - 673865= 2^{10}\cdot 2089$$

> **Theorem:** In general, for $k$ $k$th powers and co-prime terms,
>
> $$x_1^k+x_2^k+x_3^k+\dots+x_k^k = z^k\tag1$$
>
> ***if $k+1$ is prime***, then there is one $x_i$ such that  $z^k-x_i^k$ is divisible by $d_k = (k+1)^k$.

For $d_4 = 5^4 = 625$, this implies the smallest solution will have an addend $x_i >d_4/2 \approx 312$. In fact, we have,

$$30^4+120^4+\color{blue}{272}^4+315^4 = 353^4$$

and $z+x_3 =353+\color{blue}{272}=5^4$.

Incidentally, this has an analogue for $6$th powers when using *seven* addends,

$$1344^6+ 23268^6+ 25263^6+ 39088^6+ 48090^6+ \color{blue}{54138}^6+ 54018^6 = 63631^6$$

and $z+x_7 =63631+\color{blue}{54018}=7^6$.

> **Question:** Given $(1)$ *where one of the $x_i$ is zero*, is there an analogue to Ward's constraint $w_k$ for $k=6$? If there is, what is it for general $k$?

**P.S.** For *odd* powers, see also the post for [$x_1^5+x_2^5+x_3^5+x_4^5+x_5^5=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072867/)

Comment: This is finally answered in an [MO post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/206755/).

Comment: Well, change to answered question.