# On why solutions to $a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4 = (a+b+c+d)^4$ also come in pairs

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

Jacobi and Madden found infinitely many primitive solutions to,

$$a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4 = (a+b+c+d)^4$$

using an elliptic curve. We will use a different approach that, like the method for,

$$a^4+b^4+c^4 = d^4$$

discussed in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4857229/on-why-solutions-to-x4y4z4-1-come-in-pairs), also yields **pairs** of solutions.

---

**I. The system**

Define,

$$x^4+y^4+z^4+1 = (x+y+z+1)^4\tag1$$
$$\frac{x^2+x+1}{(x+y+1)(x+z+1)}=u\tag2$$
$$\frac{y^2+y+1}{(y+z+1)(y+x+1)}=v\tag3$$
$$\frac{z^2+z+1}{(z+x+1)(z+y+1)}=w\tag4$$

The variable $w$ is dependent via a rather complicated expression on $(u,v)$ so $(4)$ is redundant. Use the first three equations to solve for the three unknowns $(x,y,z)$. After some algebra, we find they are roots of **quadratics** hence yields *pairs* of solutions. The discriminant of the quadratic is,

$$D^2 = -3(2 - u + u^2)^2 + 6(2 + u + 3u^2 - 3u^3 + u^4)v - 3(5 - 6u + 6u^2 - 2u^3 + u^4)v^2 + 6(1 - u)(1 - 2u - u^2)v^3 - 3(1 - u)^2v^4$$

---

**II. Table of known *u***

If there is rational $(u,v)$ such that $D$ is also rational, then the quartic in $v$ is birationally equivalent to an elliptic curve. Furthermore, if $(u,v)$ is a solution, then $\big(\frac{u+1}{u-1},v\big)$ is also a solution and which slightly complicates things. As of 2015, there are only <strike>**eight**</strike> $u$ (*Update*: Now **twelve** as of 2024) of small height (numerator and denominator < $1000$) that are known, and not counting its partner $u'=\frac{u+1}{u-1}$. Namely,

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{#} & \color{red}u & u'=\frac{u+1}{u-1} & \color{red}v & \text{Discoverer}\\ 
\hline
1 & \dfrac{511}{450} & \dfrac{961}{61}  & \dfrac{1651}{126} & \text{Brudno}\\
\hline
2 & \dfrac{193}{18} & \dfrac{211}{175} & \dfrac{619}{450} & \text{Wroblewski}\\
\hline
3 & \dfrac{31}{6} & \dfrac{37}{25} & \dfrac{6619}{5550} & \text{Rouse} \\
\hline
4 & \dfrac{211}{150} & \dfrac{361}{61} & \dfrac{2041}{150} & \text{Tomita}\\
\hline
5 & \dfrac{157}{150} & \dfrac{307}{7} & \dfrac{8467}{150} & \text{Rouse}\\
\hline
6 & \dfrac{181}{150} & \dfrac{331}{31} & \dfrac{277567}{31675} & \text{Tomita}\\
\hline
7 & \dfrac{373}{150} & \dfrac{523}{223} & \dfrac{9785779}{952879} & \text{Tomita}\\
\hline
8 & \dfrac{121}{96} & \dfrac{217}{25} & \dfrac{6250987}{506400} & \text{Tomita}\\
\hline
\end{array}

---

**III. Example**

From the table, choose #4 and let $u=\dfrac{211}{150}$ and $v_1 =\dfrac{2041}{150}$ where $u$ was also employed by Tomita [here](http://www.maroon.dti.ne.jp/fermat/dioph168e.html) using a different method. Solving the system,

$$x^4+y^4+z^4+1 = (x+y+z+1)^4$$
$$\frac{x^2+x+1}{(x+y+1)(x+z+1)}=\frac{211}{150}$$
$$\frac{y^2+y+1}{(y+z+1)(y+x+1)}=\frac{2041}{150}$$

yields the **pair** of solutions,

$$ \left(- \frac{1984340}{107110}\right)^4 + \left( \frac{1022230}{107110}\right)^4 + \left( - \frac{1229559}{107110}\right)^4 + 1 = (x+y+z+1)^4$$

$$ \left(-\frac{3597130}{1953890}\right)^4 +  \left(- \frac{561760}{1953890}\right)^4 +  \left(- \frac{1493309}{1953890}\right)^4 + 1 = (x+y+z+1)^4$$

where $(x,y,z)$ are the first three addends. These are the 3rd and 5th smallest known solutions, also found by Tomita in the link above. From the initial $v_1$, one can find infinitely many other $v_k$.

---

**IV. Question**

So given,

$$D^2 = -3(2 - u + u^2)^2 + 6(2 + u + 3u^2 - 3u^3 + u^4)v - 3(5 - 6u + 6u^2 - 2u^3 + u^4)v^2 + 6(1 - u)(1 - 2u - u^2)v^3 - 3(1 - u)^2v^4$$

can you find a $u$ of small height not in the table above?

Comment: Are you searching  new $u$ which gives new  solutions?

Comment: @Tomita Yes, no new $u$ has been found since 2015. Maybe later we can consider old $u$ with second points $v_2$.

Comment: $(u,v)=(\dfrac{1069}{169}, \dfrac{1807}{475})$ gives new solution using old $u$? $(x,y,z)=(-\dfrac{535945811334}{1140105961325}, -\dfrac{188816130528}{228021192265}, -\dfrac{211620616362}{228021192265})$

Comment: @Tomita Yes, it is new and $(u,v) = (\dfrac{619}{450}, \dfrac{1807}{475})$ gives the same solution. I think it does not matter if $u$ or $u'$ is used.

Comment: My website [solution table](http://www.maroon.dti.ne.jp/fermat/dioph224e.html) may be useful.

Comment: @Tomita Oh, I didn't notice that newer table. I am familiar with the older table [here](http://www.maroon.dti.ne.jp/fermat/dioph168e.html).

Comment: @Tomita Did you see my [newest MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464464/difficult-elliptic-curves-for-a4b4c4d4-abcd4) for $a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4 = (a+b+c+d)^4$? I mentioned you there because you solved two of Rouse's $u$, namely u = 121/66 and u = 181/150.  Would you like to check his last three u = {163/150, 151/126, 67/42} if it is solvable by a $v$ with numerator/denominator around $10^6$?

Comment: There were no solutions for u = {163/150, 151/126, 67/42}  with height $< 10^6.$

Comment: @Tomita Ok, thanks for trying. At least it is now known it has no small solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a newer version of Tomita's table [here](http://www.maroon.dti.ne.jp/fermat/dioph224e.html), we find that Allan MacLeod found in 2017 ***four*** additional $u$ of small height, namely,

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{#} & \color{red}u & u'=\frac{u+1}{u-1} & \color{red}v & \text{Discoverer}\\ 
\hline
9 & \dfrac{511}{150} & \dfrac{661}{361}  & \dfrac{7219123}{2878098} & \text{MacLeod}\\
\hline
10 & \dfrac{499}{474} & \dfrac{973}{25} & \dfrac{80069461}{1388425} & \text{MacLeod}\\
\hline
11 & \dfrac{79}{54}  & \dfrac{133}{25} & \dfrac{29549171683987}{25656103349287} & \text{MacLeod}\\
\hline
12 & \dfrac{49}{24}  & \dfrac{73}{25} & \dfrac{138551171933011575944603377}{41031556739549840108788225} & \text{MacLeod}\\
\hline
\end{array}

with the last two also discussed in this [new MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464464/difficult-elliptic-curves-for-a4b4c4d4-abcd4) and in the last section of [MacLeod's 2017 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.03200.pdf). Given the equation $a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4 = (a+b+c+d)^4 = e^4$, then there are about $36$ known primitive solutions with $e<10^{15}$. Statistics are,

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Range #} & \text{Range of e} & \text{# of sol} \\ 
\hline
1 & 10^3-10^9 & 12\\
\hline
2 & 10^9-10^{15} & 24\\
\hline
- & \text{Total} & 36\\
\hline
\end{array}

Compare to the similar table for $a^4+b^4+c^4 = d^4$ in [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4857107/4781) where Range 2 is *also double* that of Range 1. However, since the list below is **incomplete** (a brute-force search was done by Wroblewski only for $e<2\times10^5$, [tables here](https://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/%7Ejwr/eslp/tables.htm)), then only #1 and #2 are certain, with the correct #3 probably $e<2\times10^6$. The list is arranged $(e;a,b,c,d)$ starting with the smallest $e$, with most results found before 2017.

1. 5491;   5400,                -2634,                1770,                 955, (Brudno, u = 961/61)
2. 51361; 48150,               -31764,                 27385,                  7590, (Wroblewski, u = 193/18)
3. 2084559; 1229559,             -1022230,               1984340,               -107110 (Tomita, u = 211/150)
4. 2852957; -2434795,              1945570,               1483582,               1858600 (Tomita, u = 2851/1626)
5. 3698309; 561760,              1493309,               3597130,              -1953890 (Tomita, u = 211/150)
6. 3856263; 841263,              -792940,                -44410,               3852350 (Rouse, u = 157/150)
7. 41357889; 39913670,            -23859495,              15187700,              10116014 (Rouse, u = 31/6)
8. 58169009; 53902630,              2542025,              35847220,             -34122866 (Rouse, u = 31/6)
9. 387938059; 378573600,            145514934,              65167315,            -201317790 (Tomita, u = 193/18)
10. 448785721; -336869940,           178944510,              210240721,             396470430 (Tomita)
11. 765548027; 732896170,            303742360,             189854902,            -460945405 (Tomita, u = 331/31)
12. 904758187;    753684930,            294589950,             558360120,            -701876813 (Tomita, u = 709/450)
13. 1347505009; 1338058950,            -89913570,             504106884,            -404747255 (Jacobi-Madden, u = 961/61)
14. 2056299853;  500764020,           1768211850,            1297734853,           -1510410870 (Tomita, u = 709/450)
15. 3187575799; 3095408880,           1655829870,            -157072326,           -1406590625 (Jacobi-Madden, u = 961/61)
16. 4907568427; 719130355,          -2889516060,            4672341330,            2405612802 (Tomita)
17. 5243198761;   4625798910,             46140636,            3744195265,           -3172936050 (Jacobi-Madden, u = 193/18)
18. 19606701703; 16515508578,          -10824551825,          15627586290,           -1711841340 (MacLeod)
19. 49363426793; 7784423350,          2943361793,           -10692790190,          49328431840 (Tomita, u = 157/150)
20. 66279566663; 50627178820,           1357751663,           55867457830,          -41572821650 (Tomita, u = 373/150)
21. 120237738541; 115711769730,         -64829623500,           10424211666,           58931380645 (Jacobi-Madden, u = 1651/126)
22. 183337258649; 106185491830,          80795489585,          146163232960,        -149806955726 (MacLeod)
23. 447496521629; 123140611690,         446604426005,          -96985017746,         -25263498320 (MacLeod)
24. 646013554673; 35835675310,         -168853510327,         134075405440,         644955984250 (Tomita, u = 157/150)
25. 1154082080211; -6714317914,         994485789915,         -698106854980,         864417463190 (MacLeod, u = 511/150)
26. 1398023584459; 1058103081810,         535945811334,        -1140105961325,          944080652640 (Tomita)
27. 1583248235841;  259448373800,       1526478290216,          -889698809680,         687020381505 (Tomita, u = 121/96)
28. 1777049886537; -150723250810,        1751113229630,          802797814305,         -626137906588 (Tomita, u = 331/31)
29. 1944503291223; 1796256123098, 1372056547455, -494995788100, -728813591230 (Piezas 2024, u = 2851/1626)
30. 21290372350701; 3868630767650,         895775733285,        21271390911326,       -4745425061560 (MacLeod, u = 499/474)
31. 32122121484371; 29175553438600,       5059968816155,        -21271610809130,       19158210038746 (Tomita, u = 31/6)
32. 49975792844931; 34998027446475,      32309023830920,        -42457132181770,       25125873749306, (Tomita, u = 31/6)
33. 214645386004377; -116500933664998, -4781626731970, 136060396818225, 199867549583120 (Piezas 2024, u = 2851/1626)
34. 566873307258041; -237321095011880,     558974521862416,       22424373335225,      222795507072280 (Tomita)
35. 584510799294687; 530920858665230,      377970149282480,        35966749745415,      -360346958398438 (Tomita, u = 331/31)
36. 686096520792029; 662971279500154,      309770790508565,        85290604949260,     -371936154165950 (MacLeod)

Note 1: The largest in this list is $e \approx 6.86\times10^{14}$.

Note 2: Only the smallest parameter $u = 31/6$ has four known primitive solutions within this range.

Comment: Piezas. Wolfram Alpha, gives alternate (approximate) value for 'v'. This means that there are numerical solutions, but the exact numerical ratio needs to be worked out. For example, another value is v=9.62 (for u=49/24) and v=11.78 (for u=79/54). Also, for [u=(67/42),(97/72),(103/78)] we get, [v=(10.82),(13.34),(13.86)] respectively.

Comment: @David I assume you are referring to [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464464/difficult-elliptic-curves-for-a4b4c4d4-abcd4). Approximate solutions are not acceptable when dealing with elliptic curves. And Rouse has answered that those last three $u$ may not even have solutions at all.